# Rewrite rule preserving post data

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to build a rewrite rule. I cannot redirect because I need to preserve POST and GET data. In particular, if not present I need to add the string "v1". So:

http://www.example.com/ -> http://www.example.com/v1

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "/(.*)$" "/v1/$1" [NC,L]
```

But this is not working. Can you help me please?

EDIT: with the first answer:

```
RewriteRule !^/?v1/ /v1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

http://www.example.com -> OK
http://www.example.com/v1 -> not preserving POST data (GET OK)
http://www.example.com/v1/ -> OK, please why (I just added a slash after v1, but this is not the solution I'm looking for)?
```

Comment: Are you saying that it is only preserving post if you use a trailing `/`? You are not doing a Redirect so the data should be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^/?v1/ /v1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

**EDIT:** Since `/v1/` is a directory and you're entering `http://www.example.com/v1` Apache's `mod_dir` module adds a trailing `/` to make it `http://www.example.com/v1/` using a 301 redirect. POST data gets lost due to 301 redirect.

To prevent this behavior use this snippet:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash to directories silently
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

RewriteRule !^/?v1(/.*)?$ /v1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```